# ios uiviewcontroller inheritance throws duplicate symbols error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, inheritance

I have a parent view controller with a single method I want available to all child classes:

```
#import "GAViewController.h"

@interface GAViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation GAViewController


#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


@end
```

I have a register view controller which looks like this:

```
//.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "GAViewController.h"
    #import "GAViewController.m"

    @interface GARegisterViewController : GAViewController

    @end

//.m
#import "GARegisterViewController.h"


@interface GARegisterViewController ()<UIActionSheetDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *registerButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lastNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneNumberTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *genderSegmentedContoller;

@end

@implementation GARegisterViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self makeTextFieldDelegates];
}

- (void)makeTextFieldDelegates{
    [self.userNameTextField setDelegate:self];
    [self.passwordTextField setDelegate:self];
    [self.firstNameTextField setDelegate:self];
    [self.lastNameTextField setDelegate:self];
    [self.phoneNumberTextField setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is the error I receive:
[image]
[image]

Does anyone know I can either fix the error above?  Or create a parent class correctly with the `textFieldShoudlReturn` method so that I don't have to include in all my views.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can see, I can't see the error you're getting.

Comment: I am importing .m because it contains the textfieldshouldreturn method, it also imports the .h file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am importing .m because it contains the textfieldshouldreturn method, it also imports the .h file

It is importing .m file that causes duplicate symbols. Importing a .m file causes the file from which it is imported to define the same symbols (such as method implementations and functions / variables with external scope) as the .m file being included, causing the duplication.

For the same reason one should never place `@implementation` blocks into header files.

In order to fix this, make a header for `GAViewController`, and declare `textFieldShouldReturn:` inside it. Remove `#import "GAViewController.m"` from your headers and .m files, replacing with `#import "GAViewController.h"`. This should fix the problem.

Comment: As dash says, You should not import a .m file to expose symbols defined there. Instead, add a declaration to the method `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` in the header.